# shift data and result of this operation

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I am a beginner in VHDL/FPGA and trying to understand the results of a simulation:

Example:

Let say, there is an input vector  `001001010001`.
I can shift this vector by using the following expression:

`shift_data    <=  data_in & shift_data( 0 to ( N- 2));`

How should a result for this vector look like? Could someone explain me?

EDIT 1:

```
Port
        (
data_in:     in std_logic_vector( 11 downto 0);
...
);

---

type shift_array is array (integer range 0 to 19)  of std_logic_vector ( 11 downto 0);
signal shift_data : shift_array   := (others => (others => '0')); 
...
main_process : process(Clk)
begin       
if rising_edge(Clk)  then
  if Rst = '1' then 
     data_out <=(others => '0');
   elsif Enb = '1' then
          shift_data    <=  data_in & shift_data( 0 to 18); 
   
   end if;
data_out <=  shift_data(19 to 0);      --??
end if; 
end process main_process;
```

I have checked it with test bench and gotten 0. Where have I mistaken?

Comment: Is VHDL/FPGA a software? where are you simulating?

Comment: The answer depends on the declaration of the vector, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Why do you start to use arrays now? Does it have to be 2 dimensional? It's not clear what you actually try to shift. There are several parts in your code that don't make sense

Comment: @po.pe  I implement a filter and shift -operation is a part of it. I would like to check the simulation step by step and check how the shifted data looks like. Arrays, I think it is the best option for me, later I need this array for product with filter coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [the previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562332/shift-data-and-result-of-this-operation/562334#562334), here is a corresponding schematic representation of a shifter to the right, which may further help in understanding. I assume that the code is in a clocked process.

[image: left shift register]

The trick here is to note a range (bit order), which is set by using `to` keyword instead of a usual `downto` ([reference](https://insights.sigasi.com/tech/to-downto-ranges-vhdl/)).

> `to` corresponds to big endian. So in L to R, L is the LSB and R the MSB.

Concatenation `&` works like this ([reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20210705060049/https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ejmoorkan/vhdlref/vhdl_golden_reference_guide.pdf#page=80)):

> A & B yields a vector whose length is the length of A + the length of B, with
> the content of A on the left and B on the right.

The bit order applies both to an array in the left part and concatenation. This results in the expression being equivalent to the following:

```
    shift_data(0 to (N-1)) <= data_in & shift_data(0 to (N-2));
```

which is equivalent to:

```
    shift_data(0) <= data_in;
    shift_data(1) <= shift_data(0);
    ...
    shift_data(N-1) <= shift_data(N-2);
```

The shift (with both possible directions, for a 4-bit wide register) can be seen in the following simulation results.

[image: shift register simulation results]

The corresponding testbench code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY shift_test IS
    GENERIC (N: integer := 4);
END shift_test;

ARCHITECTURE tb OF shift_test IS
    SIGNAL clk : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL data_in : STD_LOGIC; 
    SIGNAL shift_data_r, shift_data_l: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to N-1) := (others => '0'); 
BEGIN

PROCESS 
BEGIN
    clk <= '0';
    wait for 100 ns;
    clk <= '1';
    wait for 100 ns;
END PROCESS;

PROCESS 
BEGIN
    data_in <= '0';
    wait for 350 ns;
    data_in <= '1';
    wait for 500 ns;
    data_in <= '0';
    wait for 300 ns;
    data_in <= '1';
    wait for 500 ns;
END PROCESS; 

PROCESS (clk)                      
BEGIN
    IF clk'EVENT AND clk = '1' THEN
        shift_data_r <= data_in & shift_data_r(0 to (N-2));
        shift_data_l <= shift_data_l(1 to (N-1)) & data_in;
    END IF;
END PROCESS; 
    
END tb;
```

Comment: Could you please check my realisation ( EDIT in the question)?

Comment: @JangLee There are errors in your code, which prevent successful compilation, but when fixed and with proper control your listed shift register works fine for me. You really should be careful when asking for help with the code, which doesn't compile. Besides, finding errors seems to be outside of the scope of the question (and SE is all about answers for particular questions). Anyway, errors to look for: `Clk` vs `MainClk` - you will want to use only one of them, `elsif` instead of `elseif`, `;` after `end loop`, `data_out <=(others => '0');` instead of `data_out <='0'`.

Comment: i am sorry it was a part of the code I am working on, I have mistaken when I copied it. My big problem is how to sent an array to output, is it possible?

Comment: @JangLee Again, it seems to be outside the scope of the question. To get a proper answer you should ask a new question, or you can probably find an existing relevant answer. However, here is a short answer: to get all array values at an output you will have to create a very wide output, which is quite impractical. You have two reasonable options: 1) leave it as it is now, as a shift out value with one vector at a time, and use this sequence of vectors in another module, or 2) implement whatever processing you want in this module, without the need to send it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`shift_data <= data_in & shift_data(0 to N-2)` assuming `N` represents the size of `shift_data` will take in `data_in` as the new MSB and add `bit0` to `bitN-2` of the original vector. The LSB will be discarded. So with the given input vector `001001010001` and `data_in = 1` the new resulting vector will be `100100101000`.

I don't know if this is just personal preference, but I find it way more intuitive to work with the `downto` keyword instead of `to`.

**Update**
Reading the comments I have to add that I assumed that you declared the `shift_data` vector as

```
signal shift_data : std_logic_vector(0 to N-1);
```

If you use the `downto` keyword in your declaration, the answer is incorrect.

Comment: If declaration had different range, OP wouldn't get to simulation. I think your assumption is fully reasonable that the declaration uses `to` keyword and the vector is `N` bits wide.

Comment: Could you please check my realisation ( EDIT in the question)?

Comment: update: did you mean I have to write `type shift_array is array (integer range 0 to 19)  of std_logic_vector ( 0 to 11);` ? Is it important , downto or to?

Comment: The `to/downto` keyword defines the bitordering of your `std_logic_vector`, so depending on what you're doing with it, it is important.

Comment: if i need to shift an integer type of data, can I do it without a conversion into logic vector?